# Draggable SimpleModal Popup

Tags: jquery, draggable, simplemodal

For Jquery Eric Martin's SimpleModal 1.4.1 I'd like the popup to be draggable so I tried this
       $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
                onShow: function(dialog) {
                    dialog.container.draggable({ handle: 'div' });
                }
            });

the popup displays but I get an error of "object does not support property of method"

I've got jquery-ui-1.8.10 added as a script ref and class="ui-widget-content" in the div.

Ideas?

---

EDIT: removing handle: 'div' does nothing new, same error, can't move dialog

These two do **not** work, error "object does not support property of method"

```
 $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
        onShow: function(dialog) { $(dialog.container).draggable(); } 
    });


   $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
        onShow: function(dialog) { $(dialog.container).draggable({handle: 'div'}); } 
    });

console.log($(dialog.container));
Result :[object Object]
```

Comment: does it work if you remove the { handle: 'div' } part?

Comment: Try with "$(dialog.container).draggable(...)"

Comment: This is strange, I've tried at home and it work great... Can you put the result of : "console.log($(dialog.container));" ?

Comment: Here is my "console.log" content : [div#simplemodal-container.simplemodal-container]

Answer (score 1):

Hi I confirm my comment :), use this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Load dialog on page load
    //$('#basic-modal-content').modal();

    // Load dialog on click
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
            onShow: function(dialog) {
                console.log($(dialog));

                $(dialog.container).draggable();
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

You must point a DOM element !

EDIT: I have add the entry code I use.

Comment: I have the same problem but it doesn't work in IE 9 any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need to utilize the JQuery UI library, you can use the following code I found on jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/mkUJf/666/
"div#modalbox-container" could be anything.  I just chose to use the outer container of the modal.

```
//make modal draggable
$(function () {
    $('body').on('mousedown', 'div#modalbox-container', function () {
        $(this).addClass('draggable').parents().on('mousemove', function (e) {
            $('.draggable').offset({
                top: e.pageY - $('.draggable').outerHeight() / 2,
                left: e.pageX - $('.draggable').outerWidth() / 2
            }).on('mouseup', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable');
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }).on('mouseup', function () {
        $('.draggable').removeClass('draggable');
    });
});
```

Or you can add a jquery plugin like the following:
ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/

```
(function($) {
$.fn.drags = function(opt) {

    opt = $.extend({handle:"",cursor:"move"}, opt);

    if(opt.handle === "") {
        var $el = this;
    } else {
        var $el = this.find(opt.handle);
    }

    return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function(e) {
        if(opt.handle === "") {
            var $drag = $(this).addClass('draggable');
        } else {
            var $drag = $(this).addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
        }
        var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
            drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
            drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
            pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
            pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;
        $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents().on("mousemove", function(e) {
            $('.draggable').offset({
                top:e.pageY + pos_y - drg_h,
                left:e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w
            }).on("mouseup", function() {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault(); // disable selection
    }).on("mouseup", function() {
        if(opt.handle === "") {
            $(this).removeClass('draggable');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active-handle').parent().removeClass('draggable');
        }
    });

}
})(jQuery);
```

Both pieces of code are pretty much plug and play.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleModal does not have those features built-in... But you can do using JQuery..

```
$j('#simplemodal-container').draggable({ containment: "#masterpageBody" });
```

`simplemodal-container` --> Is your container `div id`

`masterpageBody` --> Is master `body id`.

we must use 'containment', to not drag beyond the screen.